# Can I sue an employer for not providing the active employment I was promised?

Tags: employment

I've been in mediations with Alorica, a call center here in my city, for some time now. I was offered employment on two campaigns, one of which was a week long, and I accepted those offers. My background information didn't come back in time for me to begin training for the week-long Pizza Hut Superbowl campaign and I was cut from the class roster for that reason. The second of these two campaigns was for Best Buy customer care, and the training class I was meant to take part in was cancelled on the client's behest. I was subsequently offered employment as a US Bank customer service agent, but due to a certain issue in my past I was unable to start with this client and was cut from the class yet again. I was then offered a job as a customer service representative with Ally Bank roughly two weeks ago and all the paperwork was completed within the proper timeframe. I have now been calling during the HR department's business hours and showing up there every day to speak with someone in the recruitment department regarding my employment status, but every time I do I am either turned away, my phone call goes unanswered and my voicemails are not returned at all.

Comment: Did you sign a contract with the employer?

Comment: Yes. There is a folder full of paperwork stating that I have been hired by Alorica that also details most of the start dates I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

What can happen with your job and the brush-offs you are getting is going to depend on the contract you signed with Alorica; there will be clauses for hiring, termination, etc. It sounds like Alorica is breaching their contract for hiring you, but that depends on what is in that contract and also on state and possibly federal employment law.

Probably the best thing to do is Google for free legal help in your area and find a lawyer who can read the contract and tell you your options. There are many NGOs and city/counties who have free legal aid clinics for civil and contractual matters such as yours.

If indeed you were contractually hired, and they are brushing you off, it's possible you could get a settlement for Alorica breaking their employment contract, but again, that depends on what is in the contract.